# Kill a tcp connection in a separate thread in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, tcp, python-multithreading

So here's the problem, I have a small server script in Python that is supposed to accept multiple clients and based on the message they are sending, receiving a certain command back to them. It's a simple concept and it's working like I want to, with one really big problem: I put each connection on hold and in separate thread, and I want when a certain connected users puts EXIT to close the connection...Which works, with one really big problem - the thread is kept alive and there is no way to kill it and that really bothers me.

```
sock = socket()
sock.bind((host,port))
sock.listen(50)

def clientthread(conn):
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024).strip()
        if(data == "HELO"):
            conn.send("HELO")
        elif(data == "EXIT"):
            conn.close()
            break
    return

while True:

    conn,addr = sock.accept()
    start_new_thread(clientthread, (conn,))

conn.close()
sock.close()
```

I searched of a way to terminate a thread but just couldn't find it, .join() is not working here since it detects the thread as "dummy", it does not recognize the __stop() and since a couple of searches on google for this topic I'm really out of options. Any idea? I'll be really grateful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't kill a thread from another - you have to arrange for the thread-to-be-killed to notice some flag has changed, and terminate itself.

BTW, your socket code looks a little off - you need a loop around your send's and recv's unless you use something like twisted or bufsock.  IMO, bufsock is much easier and less error prone than twisted, but I may be biased because I wrote bufsock.  http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/bufsock.html

The problem with what I'm seeing is that TCP reserves the right to split or aggregate transmission units.  Usually it won't, but under high load, or with a changing Path MTU, or even just Nagle, it probably will.

Comment: I know it looks strange, but for that part it works just perfectly, the server doesn't really involve in much communication with the clients, only when they send a specific command and then it gives them feedback, which is not really the issue here, my problem is cleaning those threads.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Python v2.4+, you should be using the newer Threading module. [Check out a tutorial on it here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm) - It explains the use of the threading module you're using now and how and why you should use the newer Threading module.

Comment: Yeah thanks for that, but it doesn't really help me in this case because it offers the same functionality as this one?

Comment: Granted, it isn't a direct answer to your question. But I believe moving to the newer module may resolve your current issue and help you in future.